# glClearBufferfv - not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, opengl

**EDIT: If anyone has this kind of error, and is using GLEW, when using OpenGL 4.5 functions, the following will help:**

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
```

**after that just initialize GLEW and you'll be fine.**

I´m just starting out with OpenGL. Currently I am trying to clear the whole screen with red, as seen in this code here:

```
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 720

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow *window;

    if(!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    if(!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    static GLfloat red[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        //glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        //glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

But there is a problem. I am using g++ to compile the code written in Code::Blocks. Also, I am learning with the OpenGL SuperBible 7th edition, where I got the code for clearing the screen with red. Before I was using **glClearColor(255, 0, 0, 0)** and then **glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);**
But in this book the screen is cleared with **glClearBufferfv**, which throws the following exception:

error: 'glClearBufferfv' was not declared in this scope

Of course I want to use the code in the book for learning purposes, so it would be great, if that would work. Sadly, it doesn´t. Any idea, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glClearBufferfv` is a newer OpenGL function, which means it is technically possible that a graphics card that speaks OpenGL doesn't support it. This means that the function needs to be *loaded*, either by you or by an [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library), before you can use it.

The SuperBible example code comes with the [gl3w](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) loader as part of its s7 helper library. You could either:

- use s7, which the other examples in the book will likely depend on as well
- skip s7 and use gl3w or any other loader, like my personal favourite [libepoxy](https://github.com/anholt/libepoxy)
- don't use a loader and [load the functions you need by hand](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions). This gets tedious very quick, but it does mean you get to see what's going on.

The [GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context.html#context_glext) has some useful pointers as well.

Comment: Alright, so I started using GLEW, which seems to be the best for my purposes, but now I am getting the following error: undefined reference to _imp______glewClearBufferfv                                                                                   I also tend to rather not use sb7.h, because I don´t plan on using it in the future.

Comment: That sounds like a linking problem. Have you read the [installation instructions](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) for GLEW?

Comment: Well, I tried something else in the meantime. I defined GLEW_STATIC before including glew.h, and linked to glew32s.lib, rather than to glew32.lib, but it didn´t work for me. So I guess, I´ll be using gl3w then, as you suggested (why did I even not use it? :D)                                                     One thing, I would like to ask: Is the load order for the linker correct?:              glfw3, opengl32, gdi32, include\Win32\glew32s.lib

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine around to check, but that seems sensible. If you can't get a loader to work for now, you could always just use `glfwGetProcAddress` until you do.

Comment: Could you give me a quick guide on how? I´ve never used this before. I tried: glfwGetProcAddress(glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red)); and I am certain, it´s wrong :D

Comment: The last link in my answer has an explanation on how to use `glfwGetProcAddress`, a complete example, and a link to reference documentation.